# Syntax Error on SQL INNER JOIN Query Expression

Tags: vb6

I have an error anymore, it says : "Syntax error (missing operator) in query Expression.

here's my code :

```
"SELECT AttHadir.IDUser, Hadir.NamaUser, AttHadir.JamMasuk, AttHadir.Threshold," & _
"AttHadir.ModVerifikasi, AttHadir.ModVerifikasi FROM AttHadir INNER JOIN Hadir ON AttHadir.IDUser = Hadir.IDUser" & _
"WHERE AttHadir.IDUser='" & TBox(0).Text & "' AND MONTH(AttHadir.JamMasuk) AS Bulan ='" & Combo(0).Text & "'" & _
"AND YEAR(AttHadir.JamMasuk) AS Tahun='" & Combo(1).Text & "'"
```

Is everyone know the right one of my code ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your string would be created as:

```
SELECT AttHadir.IDUser, Hadir.NamaUser, AttHadir.JamMasuk, AttHadir.Threshold,AttHadir.ModVerifikasi, AttHadir.ModVerifikasi FROM AttHadir INNER JOIN Hadir ON AttHadir.IDUser = Hadir.IDUserWHERE AttHadir.IDUser='' AND MONTH(AttHadir.JamMasuk) AS Bulan =''AND YEAR(AttHadir.JamMasuk) AS Tahun=' '
```

I think you are missing spaces before `AttHadir.ModVerifikasi`, `WHERE AttHadir.IDUser` and `AND YEAR(AttHadir.JamMasuk)`